# Trigger all jQuery events bound to an element

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have attached a click handler to a div that surrounds my radio inputs. When the div is clicked it sets the checked state of the radio, however I would also like to trigger all events bound to that radio. 
There could be multiple modules that bind to it, and they could potentially be binding on blur, change, click, dblclick, focus, hover etc.

Now I could use the following code:

```
$('.form-type-radio').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('blur').trigger('change').trigger('click').trigger('dblclick').trigger('focus').trigger('hover');
});
```

But really I would like a more succinct method - `.trigger('all')` would be perfect.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could do it like that to:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UL5kD/)

```
 $('.form-type-radio').click(function (e) {
     if(e.target != this) return;
     var input = $(this).find('input')[0],
         inputEvents = $._data(input, 'events');
     $.each(inputEvents, function (k, o) {
         $(input).triggerHandler(k);
     });
 });
```

If DIV contains more than just one input, use a `for` loop:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UL5kD/1/)

```
$('.form-type-radio').click(function (e) {
     if (e.target != this) return;
     var inputs = $(this).find('input').get();
     for (var i = 0, z = inputs.length; i < z; i++) {
         var inputEvents = $._data(inputs[i], 'events');
         $.each(inputEvents, function (k, o) {
             $(inputs[i]).triggerHandler(k);
         });
     }
 });
```

NOTE: this will only works for events bound using jQuery.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that that will trigger all events bound to the containing div .form-type-radio? I need to find the input in that div and trigger events bound to that (.find('input'))...

Comment: @FelixEve so use accurate selector. I was thinking `$('.form-type-radio')` to be a radio input, not a DIV. Or if you are talking about bubbling, use triggerHandler() instead

Comment: .form-type-radio is the containing div. I've tried using: var events = $._data($(this).find('input'),'events'),
      $self = $(this).find('input');
      $.each(events, function(k,o){
        if(k != e.type)
          $self.trigger(k);
      }); 

but I get TypeError: object is undefined on the "line length = object.length," in jQuery.js

Comment: first parameter of $._data() is DOM node, not jQuery object

Comment: Arr - so now using $(this).find('input').eq(0) but still getting  "object is undefined"?

Comment: You need `$(this).find('input').get(0)` or `$(this).find('input')[0]` to return a DOM node. But, if DIV contains more than one input, you need to iterate through array returned by `.get()`, using a `for` loop e.g

Answer (score 3):

Not something I would recommend, but maybe something like this

```
$.fn.triggerAll = function(exclude) {
    return this.each(function() {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (key.indexOf('on') === 0) {
                var ev = key.replace('on','');
                if ($.inArray(ev, exclude) == -1) {
                    $(this).trigger(ev);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

used like

```
$('.form-type-radio').click(function(e){
    $(this).triggerAll(['click', 'mousedown']); // events not to trigger
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hS9MF/3/)

I added an option to pass an array of events to exclude to avoid recursion issues.

Comment: I think the problem with this method is that is triggers the click handler that triggers the triggerAll() event so then you get a "too much recursion" error. Maybe I should just stick with specifying each event individually?

Comment: @FelixEve - That's what I said, triggering the event that triggers the event handler etc.... creates a loop.

Comment: @FelixEve - Added something to fix it.

Comment: This method seems to be working perfectly for me now - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a jQuery function to do that. a simple solution would be to add a new event to the object that would trigger all the other events. This way you have control on which events you are triggering but you don't have to trigger them every time. Something like:

```
$('input').on('all', function () {
    $(this)
        .trigger('blur')
        .trigger('change')
        .trigger('click')
        .trigger('dblclick')
        .trigger('focus')
        .trigger('hover');
});
$('input').trigger('all');
```

Comment: This method is also susceptible to the "too much recursion" error if your not careful.